# What could this slot be for?

Tags: laptop

I have an old Lenovo Ideapad Y560, and it has access panels for everything (CPU, fan, disk, RAM, internet card, the computers were so easy to repair back then) but I am still stumped on what this could be.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: The images might not show tell me if not

Comment: We can't see the images.

Comment: I assume you most probably ask about the `Express Card slot`. But [here](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/324700/Lenovo-Ideapad-Y560.html?page=32#manual) you will find all the laptop's port specifications.

Comment: No, it is not a port, but underneath there are 3 panels, one for fan/CPU/RAM, other for Internet card/Disk and another for the mystery one

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/oL0NPdL

Comment: m-SATA? or maybe some kind of PCIe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that this is slot for Mini-SATA (mSATA).
It has 8 + 18 pins and has appropriate space for device like this:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Intel_525_mSATA_SSD.jpg
Also there are two places for holdings with screws.

More description:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Mini-SATA_(mSATA)

Comment: Thanks to @Periklis [this](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/324700/Lenovo-Ideapad-Y560.html) manual says it is a slot for a sim card/tv cable thing